# Disabling Components/Setting variables in Scripts of another object in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my player hits and enemy, ive programmed in to add an impulse force:

```
        if (health = collider.GetComponent<Health>())
        {
            health.GetHit(damage, transform.parent.gameObject);

            var enemyTransform = collider.GetComponent<Transform>();
            var enemyRB2D = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            var knockbackDirection = (enemyTransform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            enemyRB2D.AddForce(knockbackDirection * knockbackStrength, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            

        }
```

This works, however, I am moving my enemy in fixed update with:
`rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);`

Therefore these commands are in conflict, and as the movement is constantly happening, no knockback is being dealt.

I've tried several solutions, such as: `collider.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().enabled = false;` , or setting the bool "stunned" to be true then in the enemy only allow movement if not stunned, etc.
But all of these come back with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I'm not sure what to do now, any help is greatly appreciated.